# How to get iexplore.exe process types as managed in Attach to Process box of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional Version. (.NET Application/Project)

In the `Debug Menu > attach to process > iexplore.exe` process type is coming as `x86`, `x64` but I need to get `managed(x86)`, `managed(x64)` in the type column of `iexplore.exe` process.

Even I did a few things like

1. Opened Visual Studio as administrator
2. Deleted all the browser's cache, old DLL's, etc.
3. clean and rebuilt the solutions

Still, I'm not getting the `iexplore.exe` process as a managed type.
Could anyone please help me with this problem!!!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it would need to be a .NET application in order for the process type to be managed. You can't magically make an application .NET if it's not. Unless I'm missing something (which is not impossible), you're out of luck.

Comment: Before asking us how to, tell us why you need that. VS debugger only shows a process as "managed" when it indeed loads CLR inside. `iexplorer.exe` is the process for Internet Explorer, which only loads CLR in very very rare cases (and for legacy technologies), so you are not supposed to go that direction.